# Maintaining Mule Message

Tags: java, http, jersey, mule

Similar to this discussion [Maintain Payload State during mule flow execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20568646/maintain-payload-state-during-mule-flow-execution?newreg=7832a20ffd864150a098e1485912f9bc)

I would like to know how to maintain an entire Mule Message throughout my flow. 
I am trying to call a jersey resource component after I have received information that the user is authorized to call it. In this authorization request the payload and original http request gets altered.

My predicament is that I don't want to call the resource first as that would be inefficient and insecure however I cannot see any other plausible way to do this.

```
<flow name="test">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="0.0.0.0" port="1234" path="test" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <!-- sub-flow here which changes the MuleMessage and loses all original inbound properties -->

    <jersey:resources doc:name="REST">
        <component class="com.Test" />
    </jersey:resources>
</flow>
```

Thanks for any help in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mule 3 includes two [scopes](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Scopes) that will allow you to preserve the original message, while executing other message processors:

1. If you must wait for the sub-flow to complete because you need to use information produced by the sub-flow, use a [message enricher](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Message+Enricher) like so.  This example assigns the variable "authorized" to whatever the payload is once the sub-flow finishes processing the message.

   `<enricher target="#[variable:authorized]">
       <flow-ref name="checkAuthorization" />
   </enricher>`
2. If you do not need to wait for the sub-flow to complete before allowing your Jersey Resource to run, use the [async](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Async+Scope+Reference) scope like so:

   `<async>
       <flow-ref name="goForthAndDoSomething" />
   </async>`

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to save a mule message and it's properties so that it could be retrieve when required .. In your case you could save the entire Mule message in a variable and retrieve it when required for example :

```
<flow name="test">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="0.0.0.0" port="1234" path="test" doc:name="HTTP"/>
   <!-- You save your entire message in a session variable named entireMessage before calling a subflow-->
<set-session-variable variableName="entireMessage" value="#[message.payload]" />
 <!-- You can now call your Sub flow -->

    <jersey:resources doc:name="REST">
        <component class="com.Test" />
    </jersey:resources>
</flow>
```

Here in the above flow you store your Mule message in a session variable named **entireMessage** .. You can easily retrieve the value of this session variable whenever you need in any flow anywhere like the following :-

```
<logger level="INFO" message="#[sessionVars['entireMessage']]"/>
```

This will print you Mule message

There is also an **alternative way** to store the http headers before it get altered ..
you can also use the following :-

```
<flow name="test">
 <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="0.0.0.0" port="1234" path="test" doc:name="HTTP"/>
       <!-- You copy all the HTTP headers before calling a subflow-->
 <copy-properties propertyName="http.*" doc:name="Copy All HTTP Headers"/>  
  <!-- You can now call your Sub flow -->

   <jersey:resources doc:name="REST">
      <component class="com.Test" />
    </jersey:resources>
</flow>
```

The above flow will copy all the HTTP headers before calling any other flow

**UPDATED FLOW :-**

If you need the **original unaltered payload** for your Jersy component , please **overwrite** the **current payload** with the **original payload** stored in session variable using **set payload component**

```
 <flow name="test">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="0.0.0.0" port="1234" path="test" doc:name="HTTP"/>
       <!-- You save your entire message in a session variable named entireMessage before calling a subflow-->
    <set-session-variable variableName="entireMessage" value="#[message.payload]" />
     <!-- You can now call your Sub flow -->

 <!-- overwrite current payload with original unaltered payload -->   
<set-payload value="#[sessionVars['entireMessage']]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        <jersey:resources doc:name="REST">
            <component class="com.Test" />
        </jersey:resources>
    </flow>
```

Comment: Even if I set the mule message in a variable, the jersey component still looks at the current payload. I believe that the jersey component relies on the content of the **current** mule message. @anirban-sen-chowdhary

Comment: Yes that is sure .. but the question is what you want to do with the original payload?? do you want to put the origal payload for jersy component ?? in that case overwrite the current payload with the original payload using set payload component ... pls look at my updated flow ...

Comment: That does contain the payload I am after but doesn't contain any of the http headers that I need to make the request. How do I do the equivalent but for all the header properties?

Comment: You use <copy-properties propertyName="http.*" doc:name="Copy All HTTP Headers"/> after http inbound endpoint that will copy all the HTTP headers you need ..

Comment: One more thing also please change it to <set-session-variable variableName="entireMessage" value="#[message]" />  from <set-session-variable variableName="entireMessage" value="#[message.payload]" /> as #[message] will contain entire Mule message

Comment: I've changed the session property to #message and the error message I get is:The Session Property "entireMessage" is not serializable and will be lost when MuleSession is serialized or propagated over a transport.

Comment: Please check your expression .. it will be #[message] and not #message as you have written here .. so the total expression will be <set-session-variable variableName="entireMessage" value="#[message]" /> ..

Comment: From what you have said, it seems possible to reproduce the original payload within the MuleMessage after it has been changed by the sub-flow, as well as maintaining a copy of the inbound properties. The only thing that is missing is that the current MuleMessage, at the point where  the Jersey component kicks in, needs to have the original inbound properties as it's inbound properties - not simply copied and stored elsewhere. But by this point they will have been changed by the sub-flow.

Comment: You can also store the current payload in a session variable in the same way you stored the original message and can use it whenever you required ....

Comment: One more thing better use <copy-properties propertyName="http.*" doc:name="Copy All HTTP Headers"/>  to copy the original http headers and call the subflow using VM component rather than using flowRef

Answer (score 0):

Try somthing like this to store the original message in session:

```
    <message-properties-transformer scope="session" doc:name="Save original message">
        <add-message-property key="originalMessage" value="#[message:payload]"></add-message-property>
    </message-properties-transformer>
```

Then try something like this to get it from session:

```
<expression-transformer evaluator="..." expression="SESSION:originalMessage" doc:name="Restore original message"></expression-transformer>
```

Comment: Even if I set the mule message in a variable, the jersey component still looks at the current payload. I believe that the jersey component relies on the content of the **current** mule message.  @andres

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your help. The final solution answer was:

```
<flow name="test">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="0.0.0.0" port="1234" path="test" doc:name="HTTP"/>

    <enricher target="#[variable:unwantedPayload]" source="#[payload]">
        <flow-ref name="anotherFlowCalled" />
    </enricher>

    <jersey:resources doc:name="REST">
        <component class="com.Test" />
    </jersey:resources>
</flow>
```

Answer (score 0):

best way to store the mule message into session , whether you flow contains subflows are private flow session vars carry till end of the execeution.