# Mule tag namespace unbound

Tags: mule

I searched a bit through this site and found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25910876/maintaining-mule-message) . My issue is i am calling another flow inside the flow and when i get the response from another flow i just to need check for a message property(i used a filter). However, when i come to set-payload tag i get error that **namespace associated with element "set-payload" is not bound**.

```
<flow name = "XXXX">
    <set-session-variable variableName="originalMessage" value="#[message.payload]" />
    <choice>
      <when>
          <custom-filter class="xxxx" />
          <flow ref="YYYY" />
      </when>
      <otherwise>
          <flow ref="errorHandler" />
      </otherwise>
    </choice>
    <choice>
        <when><customer-filter="another filter to check response from the flow YYYY" />
    <!-- error occurs below -->
    <set-payload value="#[sessionVars['originalMessage']]" doc:name="Set Payload" />
    <!-- do stuff -->
</flow>
```

Comment: Why using filters in a `choice` router? This is defeating the purpose of this router: you're supposed to have conditions on the `when` elements instead of these `filters`.

Comment: Also what Mule version? Can you show the complete configuration, or at least how you defined the namespaces at the top.